# Numpy Array Column Slicing Produces IndexError: invalid index Exception

Tags: numpy

I am using version 1.5.1 of numpy and Python 2.6.6.

I am reading a binary file into a numpy array:

```
>>> dt = np.dtype('<u4,<i2,<i2,<i2,<i2,<i2,<i2,<i2,<i2,u1,u1,u1,u1')
>>> file_data = np.fromfile(os.path.join(folder,f), dtype=dt)
```

This works just fine. Examining the result:

```
>>> type(file_data)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> file_data
array([(3571121L, -54, 103, 1, 50, 48, 469, 588, -10, 0, 102, 0, 0),
   (3571122L, -78, 20, 25, 45, 44, 495, 397, -211, 0, 102, 0, 0),
   (3571123L, -69, -48, 23, 60, 19, 317, -26, -151, 0, 102, 0, 0), ...,
   (3691138L, -53, 52, -2, -11, 76, 988, 288, -101, 1, 102, 0, 0),
   (3691139L, -11, 21, -27, 25, 47, 986, 253, 176, 1, 102, 0, 0),
   (3691140L, -30, -19, -63, 59, 12, 729, 23, 302, 1, 102, 0, 0)],
  dtype=[('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', '<i2'), ('f2', '<i2'), ... , ('f12', '|u1')])

>>> file_data[0]
(3571121L, -54, 103, 1, 50, 48, 469, 588, -10, 0, 102, 0, 0)

>>> file_data[0][0]
3571121    

>>> len(file_data)
120020
```

When I try to slice the first column:

```
>>> file_data[:,0]
```

I get:

```
IndexError: invalid index.
```

I have looked at simple examples and was able to do the slicing:

```
>>> a = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)])
>>> a[:,0]
array([1, 4])
```

The only difference I can see between my case and the simple example is that I am using the dtype. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: you should accept the answer below if it was useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you set the dtype like that, you are creating a [Record Array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).  Numpy treats that like a 1D array of elements of your dtype.  There's a fundamental difference between

```
file_data[0][0]
```

and

```
file_data[0,0]
```

In the first, you are asking for the first element of a 1D array and then retrieving the first element of that returned element.  In the second, you are asking for the element in the first row of the first column of a 2D array.  That's why you are getting the `IndexError`.

If you want to access an individual element using 2D notation, you can create a [view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) and work with that.  Unfortunately, AFAIK if you want to treat your object like a 2D array, all elements have to have the same dtype.